# Get the count of the words `href` and `nofollow` from each row of a table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `Posts` wherein the column named `HTMLBody` contains the html content like `href` and `nofollow`, and i want the count of each one of them from each row. `[i.e. occurrence]`

**Expected Output -**

[image]

What i've tried is below example -

```
Declare @string varchar(1000)
Set @string = '<p><font color=#000080>Hello Paul,</font></p>  <p><font color=#000080>I would try <span><a href="http://www.neuraltherapy.com/" target=_blank rel=nofollow><font color=#003399>www.neuraltherapy.com</font></a>&nbsp;and give them a call to find a practitioner in your area.</span></font></p>'
select (len(@string) - len(replace(@string, 'href', '')))/4 as 'href'
select (len(@string) - len(replace(@string, 'nofollow', '')))/8 as 'nofollow'
```

**Current demo output-**

[image]

How do i proceed to get the result as expected result above. OR any other query would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Really a great logic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated -**

```
select @string, 
  (len(@string) - len(replace(@string, 'href', '')))/4 as 'href',
  (len(@string) - len(replace(@string, 'nofollow', '')))/8 as 'nofollow'
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 3):

You just want this in one `select`, not two:

```
select @string,
       (len(@string) - len(replace(@string, 'href', ''))) / 4 as href
       (len(@string) - len(replace(@string, 'nofollow', ''))) / 8 as nofollow
```

You can, of course, do this for columns in a table as well:

```
select HTMLBody,
       (len(HTMLBody) - len(replace(HTMLBody, 'href', ''))) / 4 as href
       (len(HTMLBody) - len(replace(HTMLBody, 'nofollow', ''))) / 8 as nofollow
from Posts;
```

Comment: Thanks. But its gives err `Incorrect syntax near 'len'.`